# Not able to access the console when I install a guest VM on a KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, command-line-interface, debian-squeeze, console, guest

I am trying to write a script for installing a guest VM on a KVM using virt-install.
I have a knoppix live cd based iso. The underlying OS is Debian 6.0.2.

I am using this command to install the guest vm :

```
virt-install --name wanem --memory 2048 --vcpus 2 -c /home/tester/images/wanem/WANem_3.0_Beta.iso \
             --network default --noautoconsole --nodisks --livecd --console pty,target_type=virtio
```

This is the output :

```
WARNING  No operating system detected, VM performance may suffer. Specify an OS with --os-variant for optimal results.

Starting install...
Domain creation completed.
```

But if I try to access the console of the guest VM, I am not able to connect to the console :

```
admin@UbuntuHostKVM:~$ virsh console wanem
Connected to domain wanem
Escape character is ^]
```

The device shows up if I do virsh list :

```
admin@UbuntuHostKVM:~$ virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 177   wanem                          running
```

This is the output of /etc/libvert/qemu/wanem.xml:

```
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh edit wanem
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>wanem</name>
  <uuid>e74e11e7-0200-43e9-a09f-4defae2a25e6</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-bionic'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Skylake-Server-IBRS</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/tester/images/wanem/WANem_3.0_Beta.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:94:85:62'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='virtio' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I do not have access to the UI of the host machine/guest vm. I want to be able to access the console without doing anything on the UI.

This is the first time I am using libvirt and virt-install.
I need access to the console of the guest VM.
If there is some better way of doing this or if I am doing anything wrong please let me know.

Comment: I suppose the ISO wants to output to the framebuffer, not a serial console. Try adding an option for graphics output, for example `--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0`, then using a VNC viewer to see Knoppix.